# CORS vs CORB, what's the difference?

Tags: cors, cross-origin-read-blocking

I read the documents about [CORB](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers), but I couldn't find difference between CORS and CORB. They both based on CORS policy and prevent sharing data between different cross origin web sites.
What's the difference of it? Does CORB is part of CORS?

Comment: Looks like CORS concerns writing (POST request) while this one concerns reading sensitive info from web pages.

Answer (score 1):

From this remarkable post (https://scotthelme.co.uk/coop-and-coep/) I would simply say that based on the latest threads/attacks from [spectre and meltdown](https://spectreattack.com/) the w3c has created the new "COEP COOP CORP CORS CORB".

To keep things simple, let's say the difference between them two it that the CORB policy will help you prevent an attack of the hostile page requesting a Data Resource (like HTML/XML/JSON) but making it look like it's requesting a Media Resource (like an image/JS/XSS).

I encourage you to read the full post, since it provide me a ton of clarity :)